# joda-time library pattern "d" not translating locale language

Tags: android, locale, jodatime, android-jodatime

I am using **joda-time** library for my Android project instead of **Calendar**. but unlike calendar I am facing a problem with locale language.

According to system/device language all type of text is translating but the "d" pattern is not translating, it always stays in English language.

Like say with "d" pattern, if a variable is 15, for English language locale it is: 15,
but for Arabic language locale it is still: 15, it should convert to arabic 15 (١٥). It is not translating.

How can I do this? is this something joda-time lib does not support, or I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Check the following notice at the [Home Page of Joda-Time](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/)

> Joda-Time is the de facto standard date and time library for Java
> prior to Java SE 8. Users are now asked to migrate to java.time
> (JSR-310).

**Using the modern date-time API:**

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();
        DateTimeFormatter dtfArabic = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE.localizedBy(Locale.forLanguageTag("ar-SA"));
        System.out.println(date.format(dtfArabic));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
٢٠٢١-٠٢-٠٤
```

Learn more about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).